# Timer in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Timer in reactJS that goes from 05:00 to 00:00

here is the code:

```
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(60);
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(5);
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTimer((prevTimer) => {
                if (prevTimer <= 1) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    setDisable(false);
                }
                return prevTimer - 1;
            });
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);

        };
    }, [disable]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setMinutes((prevMinutes) => {
                if (minutes === 0) clearInterval(interval);
                return prevMinutes - 1;
            })

        }, 60000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        const minutesInterval = setInterval(() => {
            setSeconds((secondsCount) => {
                if (secondsCount <= 1 && minutes === 0) {
                    clearInterval(minutesInterval);
                }
                if (secondsCount <= 0) {
                    if (minutes !== 1 && minutes !== 5) {
                        setMinutes((prevMinutes) => prevMinutes - 1);
                    }
                    return 59;
                }
                return secondsCount - 1;
            });
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(minutesInterval);
    }, []);
```

it doesn't work correctly. (i also have a timer from 60 seconds to zero which works correctly, the first one), it goes from 05:59 to 05:00 then to 04:00 and then to 04:59

Comment: Why do you need two separate states + timers for seconds/minutes? It would be much simpler to just have one state and one timer, then format to/from a total number of seconds when setting/displaying the value

Comment: It's better to use something like `performance.now()` because timers are throttled when the document gets out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 timers to do that, just one is enough

```
const [timerValue, setTimerValue] = useState(300) // number of seconds

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTimerValue((currentValue) => currentValue - 1);
  }, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
},[]);
```

Then you can use something like this to display the current time :

```
const [minutes, seconds] = useMemo(() => {
  const min = Math.floor(timerValue / 60);
  const sec = timerValue % 60;
  return [min, sec];
}, [timerValue]);
```